# groups: cannot find name for group ID #########

Tags: users

This is a variant of the unresolved 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/295610/cannot-find-name-for-group-id-26739201
but I'll post it here again since I have some more information

I recently made a fresh installation of 14.04 so most things "should" be clean.

When I open the terminal, I get this error message

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID ######
```

The group number changes every time I log out and log in again:

```
###### = 1097638658
###### = 1097638674
###### = 1097638677
###### = 1097638680
###### = 1097638683
###### = 1097646472 (here I also rebooted)
```

on subsequent logins.

At the same time I notice that I have problems creating new users from the settings menu. 
I can create new users but not set their password. If I let the new users be without password I get kicked out whenever I try to log in with them.

Any ideas?

[EDIT]

Starting the shell (today) and asking for id I get

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 1097972621
mikael@glasbult:~$ id
uid=1000(mikael)gid=1000(mikael),groups=1000(mikael),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),1097972621
```

At the end out the output I notice a matching id: 1097972621

[NEW INFO]

Not sure if I should answer my own question or put it here. I mentioned the problem to my local sysadmin and he said the strange group number is an AFS-artefact. It's necessary for PAG, which gives a user the same rights in all sub-shell.
Thus it's not an error, just an ugly nuisance.

Case closed I suppose.

Comment: Please add the output of `id`.

Comment: Mikael, I'd recommend answering the question, but adding as much info as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue on a machine I'm provisioning, but I don't yet know how to solve the problem directly, which in my case involves LDAP group enumeration.

However, `/etc/bash.bashrc` has a configurable flag to disable the section of `bashrc` that checks to see whether it should remind you how to use sudo.  It is that section of `bashrc` that calls `groups(1)`, which generates the error you are seeing.

To disable that check, and thus work around this error message, you can:

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the message by commenting the following lines related to `sudo` hint in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
# sudo hint
##if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
##    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *|*\ sudo\ *)
##    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
##      cat <<-EOF
##      To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
##      See "man sudo_root" for details.
##
##      EOF
##    fi
##    esac
##fi
```